# Correct use of expectLastCall().once() in EasyMock

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock

I'm writing a junit test for a particular method. The method contains calls to other methods in a DAO class which I am mocking with EasyMock.

I want to assert that one of these DAO class methods is called once, which is what I assume expectLastCall().once() is for. The method in question returns void.

The test I have currently passes, I just want to make sure my logic is correct as I haven't used EasyMock before. I used this question as a reference: [EasyMock expectations with void methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917312/easymock-expectations-with-void-methods)

So, here is the code:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
    this.fooService = new FooService();
    this.fooMock = createStrictMock(FooDAO.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_fooTest(){

    String arg1 = "arg1";
    String arg2 = "arg2";
    this.fooService.setFooDAO(fooMock);
    expect(this.fooMock.someMethod(arg1, arg2)).andReturn(something);
    fooMock.methodThatShouldBeCalledOnce(EasyMock.<Object>anyObject());
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
    replay(this.fooMock);
    this.fooService.methodUnderTest(someArg, someArg2);
    verify(this.fooMock);

    }
```

What I think this does is assert that there is a call to methodThatShouldBeCalledOnce and that it only happens once. I don't really care about someMethod but of course EasyMock complains if it's not told to expect it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct to me. You could easily check by yourself by removing the call to the void method and verify that the test fails, or by adding a second call to the void method and see that the test also fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about some methods, you should create a nice mock. Then, indeed, there's no need to call expectLastCall. It is implicit but can be a good practice to make it obvious you are mocking a method. once() is also not needed since it is the default.

So, if a rephrase it, using a nice mick, removing implicit calls, adding static imports and not adding redundant "this", you should get:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
   fooService = new FooService();
   fooMock = createNiceMock(FooDAO.class);
   fooService.setFooDAO(fooMock);
}

@Test
public void test_fooTest(){  
   fooMock.methodThatShouldBeCalledOnce(anyObject());

   replay(fooMock); // or replayAll() if you extend EasyMockSupport

   fooService.methodUnderTest(someArg, someArg2);
   verify(fooMock); // or verifyAll() if you extend EasyMockSupport
}
```